# How to get Value from form (symfony 1.4)

Tags: php, forms, symfony1

I've made complex form which is valid in action. I'd like to get value from this input to save file on server.

```
<input type="text" 
    name="produkty[pForm][1][caption]" 
    id="produkty_pForm_1_caption" />
```

I've tried something like that:

```
$this->form=new ProduktyForm();

if ($request->isMethod(sfRequest::POST))
{
   $this->form->bind($request->getParameter('produkty'),$request->getFiles('produkty'));
   if ( $this->form->isValid())
   {
       $file=$this->form->getValue('produkty[pForm][1][src]');
       $filename='u';
       $extension = $file->getExtension($file->getOriginalExtension());
       $file->save(sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir').'/'.$filename.$extension);
   }
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is usually _always_ an insufficient error description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'produkty' is the name of your form. Are you using a subform to capture an array of possible files to be input?

You could get the values of the entire form by doing this.

```
$form_vals = $this->form->getValues();
```

Then you could could see what variables you have by your output.

You'll probably be able to get the input this way.

```
$caption = $form_vals['pForm'][1]['caption'];
```

this is working fine but how to fetch the values  from file attributes . i cant get the values from file input 
my main form name is slide and subform is mslide

here is the my code

```
$this->multiSlideForm->bind($request->getParameter('slide'), $request->getFiles('slide'));
$form_vals = $this->multiSlideForm->getValues();
echo $form_vals['mslide'][0]['slide_name']; //working
echo $this->multiSlideForm->getValue('[mslide][0][file_name]')->getOriginalName();  //not working
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm using Symfony <3 , legacy version, and
`form.getObject.getReplyTypeId` works for me, replace `getReplyTypeId` with the getter of any property you may need from the object